# Pulling a random value out of a table is returning a null value

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have a stored procedure that I've used to 'de-identify' client information when I want to use it in a test environment.  I am replacing actual names and addresses with random values.  I have database tables in a database called dict (for dictionary) for female names, male names, last names, and addresses.

Each of these has a field called f_row_id that is a sequential number from 1 to x, one for each record in the table.

We recently upgraded to mySQL 8 and the stored procedure quit working.  I ended up with NULL for every field where I tried filling in a random value out of the other table.  In trying to find what will now work, I'm unable to get the following query to work as I expect:

```
SELECT
    f_enroll_id,
    (SELECT f_name FROM dict.dummy_female_first_name fn WHERE fn.f_row_id = (FLOOR(RAND() * 850)  + 1) LIMIT 1)
FROM
    t_enroll
```

My data table (that I eventually want to have contain random names) is called t_enroll.  There is an ID field in that (f_enroll_id)  I want to get a list of each ID and a random first name for each record in that table.

There are 850 records in the table of random first names (dummy_female_first_name) (in my stored procedure this is a session variable that I compute at the start of the procedure).

When I first tried running this I got an error that my sub-query returned more than one value.  I don't understand why it would do that since (FLOOR(RAND() * 850)  + 1) should return a single integer.  So I added the LIMIT 1.  But when I run this, about half of the returned rows have NULL for the first name.

I have verified that all the rows in my first name table have a row ID, that the row ID is unique, and there not any gaps in the numbers.

What do you think is causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the schema for the table that I'm updating:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `t_enroll` (
  `f_enroll_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `f_status` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_date_enrolled` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `f_first_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_mi` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_last_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `f_maiden_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_dob` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `f_date_fee_received` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `f_gender` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `f_address_1` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_address_2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_quadrant` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_city` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_state` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `f_county` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `f_zip_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`f_enroll_id`),
  KEY `f_date_enrolled` (`f_date_enrolled`),
  KEY `f_last_name` (`f_last_name`),
  KEY `f_first_name` (`f_first_name`),
  KEY `f_dob` (`f_dob`),
  KEY `f_gender` (`f_gender`)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=532 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='InnoDB free: 15360 kB';
```

Here is the schema for the dictionary table where I pull names from:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `dummy_female_first_name` (
  `f_row_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `f_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`f_row_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As I mentioned in my comment, I have found an alternate approach using the ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 variation.  But I am still curious as to what is going on that prevented my original method to fail.  This is something that changed in the more recent mySQL version because it used to work.

Thanks again.

Comment: please show your schema (output of `show create table dict.dummy_female_first_name` and `show create table t_enroll`) and sample data the reproduces the problem

Comment: Obviously I am still learning about posting here because I'm not sure how to provide my schema.  When I try to add it as a comment, it says my comment is too long.  Should I post the schema in multiple small comments?

Comment: By the way, I have found a way around it.  If I change: (SELECT f_name FROM dict.dummy_female_first_name fn WHERE fn.f_row_id = (FLOOR(RAND() * 850)  + 1) LIMIT 1) to (SELECT f_name FROM dict.dummy_female_first_name fn ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) it works.

Comment: no, just edit your question and add it.  comments are not very useful for code or sql

Answer (score 0):

It is a much more expensive approach, but you can use:

```
SELECT f_enroll_id,
        (SELECT f_name FROM dict.dummy_female_first_name fn ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1)
FROM t_enroll;
```

You can make this more efficient using:

```
SELECT f_enroll_id,
        (SELECT f_name
         FROM dict.dummy_female_first_name fn 
         WHERE rand() < 0.01
         ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
        )
FROM t_enroll;
```

The `where` clause means that about 8 rows will filter through so the sorting will be much faster.